# Is there a way for getting the final value on the event.target.value emitted by the onChange function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am using a barcode reader to input the data. So using the `onChange` function a textbox, the data is emitted as a stream of characters like so 1 2 3 4 to have the final value as 1234.

In my case I just want to get the final value as 1234 then evoke another method.

Comment: You can listen to the close event to know exactly when the streaming is closed.

Comment: You can apply some kind of debouncing

Comment: ``setBarCode(prev => `${prev}${e.target.value}`)``

Comment: @Héctor how because you will not be knowing the length of the code that will be scanned.